# I'm trying to prove that $ (n+1)!-1 = \sum_{i=1}^n i • i! $ combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to prove this identity combinatorially:

$$  (n+1)!-1 = \sum_{i=1}^n i • i!  $$

I tried to ask and answer the question:
In how many ways can we list (n+1) different numbers such that we don't list the numbers in ascending order.

The left side is clearly (n+1)! -1, but how do I prove that that applies to the right side as well? I would appreciate any hints!

Comment: Note:  many of the arguments given in the duplicate are, in fact, proofs by induction, but there is a good combinatorial proof in the solutions.

Comment: @lulu Yes you are right, I really tried to find it before posting this question, but no result... Thank you